# Open sets in subspace $Y$ of $ X = [0,1]^{2}$ with order topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $ X = [0,1]^{2}$  be a topological space with order topology ( lexicographic order) and $ Y= [0, 1) ×\left\{0,\frac{1}{2} \right\}\subset X$ a subspace of $X$.
Why are $ [0, 1) ×\left\{\frac{1}{2} \right\}$  and $ [0, 1) ×\left\{0\right\}$ open in Y?

I think $ [0, 1) ×\left\{\frac{1}{2} \right\}$  is open because we can take intervals around $( \frac{1}{2}, x), x\in [0,1)$ and look at their union and intersect it with Y.
But what about $ [0, 1) ×\left\{0\right\}$?

Comment: $[0,1) \times \{0\}=\{x\in X: x<(1,0)\}$

Comment: No, $(\frac12,\frac12) < (1,0)$ in the lexicographical order.

Comment: @Ingix I agree, so is it not open then? I can't think of an open set in X which when intersected with Y gives $ [0, 1) ×\left\{0\right\}$

Comment: @user15269: Can you check that you didn't mess up the factor order in the cross products of the first parapgraph (as you already did in the second paragraph)?  I ask because neither set is open the way you wrote the crossproducts (any neighbourhood of a point $(x,y) \in Y$ with $x \neq 0$ will contain points with both second value $0$ and $\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $U$ is an open subset of $Y$ that contains $(t,0) \in Y$, where $0< t < 1$. Then $U$ contains a set of the form $((a,b), (c,d)) \cap Y$ where $(a,b),(c,d) \in [0,1] \times [0,1]$ and $(t,0)$ lies in that open interval by the definition of the order topology and the definition of subspace topology.

But then $a <t$ ($t \le a$ would cause $(a,b) \ge (t,0)$ and we can find $a'$ with $a < a' < t$. But then $(a',\frac12) \in ((a,b), (c,d)) \cap Y$ so $U \nsubseteq [0,1) \times \{0\}$.

It follows that no point $(t,0) \in (0,1) \times \{\frac12\}$ is an interior point of $[0,1) \times \{\frac12\}$ in $Y$. So that subset of $Y$ is not open and there mist be some mistake in the exercise or your rendering of it.